# Calculating billing periods for traffic accounting

Tags: mysql, date

I'm trying to figure out how to do some traffic accounting via MySQL that I can split into billing months.

I have a table (traffic_logs) that has:

> date | ip | inbound | outbound | last_updated

That gets populated / updated to give a daily tally.

I have a services table that has:

> service_name | expires | ipaddr

I currently use a query such as:

```
SELECT SUM(inbound) AS traffic_in, SUM(outbound) AS traffic_out
FROM services
JOIN traffic_logs ON services.ip = traffic_logs.ip
GROUP BY ip
ORDER BY service_name;
```

Where I'm getting stuck is that I want to find the traffic for the current billing month.

Example data set:

```
traffic_logs table:
+---------------+------------+------------+------------+---------------------+
|      ip       |    date    |  inbound   |  outbound  |    last_updated     |
+---------------+------------+------------+------------+---------------------+
| 192.168.1.100 | 2014-10-08 |   40372536 |  454591053 | 2014-10-08 23:55:03 |
| 192.168.1.100 | 2014-10-09 |   22275659 |  241704264 | 2014-10-09 23:55:03 |
| 192.168.1.100 | 2014-10-10 |   23481329 |  350904975 | 2014-10-10 23:55:03 |
| 192.168.1.100 | 2014-10-11 |   28148019 |  177964416 | 2014-10-11 23:55:04 |
| 192.168.1.100 | 2014-10-12 |   46099322 | 1383179073 | 2014-10-12 23:55:05 |
| 192.168.1.100 | 2014-10-13 |   30171788 |  177338415 | 2014-10-13 23:55:06 |
| 192.168.1.100 | 2014-10-14 |   22821090 |  260455364 | 2014-10-14 23:55:07 |
| 192.168.1.100 | 2014-10-15 |   30049347 |  206231505 | 2014-10-15 23:55:07 |
| 192.168.1.100 | 2014-10-16 |   33703952 |  413556561 | 2014-10-16 23:55:09 |
| 192.168.1.100 | 2014-10-17 |   32386602 |  533711743 | 2014-10-17 23:55:10 |
| 192.168.1.100 | 2014-10-18 |   34650714 |  576704272 | 2014-10-18 23:55:10 |
| 192.168.1.100 | 2014-10-19 |   41040926 |  636292627 | 2014-10-19 23:55:10 |
| 192.168.1.100 | 2014-10-20 |   40022284 |  542582298 | 2014-10-20 23:55:12 |
| 192.168.1.100 | 2014-10-21 |   98535882 |  336734189 | 2014-10-21 23:55:12 |
| 192.168.1.100 | 2014-10-22 |   41569882 |  292757699 | 2014-10-22 23:55:13 |
| 192.168.1.100 | 2014-10-23 | 2147483647 |  934724220 | 2014-10-23 23:55:01 |
| 192.168.1.100 | 2014-10-24 | 2147483647 |  462654543 | 2014-10-24 23:55:01 |
| 192.168.1.100 | 2014-10-25 |  312027896 |  321416702 | 2014-10-25 23:55:01 |
| 192.168.1.100 | 2014-10-26 |   34953533 |  341663241 | 2014-10-26 23:55:03 |
| 192.168.1.100 | 2014-10-27 |   34335294 |  236423425 | 2014-10-27 23:55:03 |
| 192.168.1.100 | 2014-10-28 |   34919816 |  492949009 | 2014-10-28 16:00:03 |
+---------------+------------+------------+------------+---------------------+
```

```
services table:
+---------------+------------+---------------+
| service_name  |  expires   |      ip       |
+---------------+------------+---------------+
| my_web_server | 2014-11-29 | 192.168.1.100 |
| my_ftp_server | 2014-11-15 | 192.168.1.101 |
+---------------+------------+---------------+
```

When the service is renewed, it is renewed as `expires=DATE_ADD(expires, INTERVAL 1 MONTH)`.

Now I'm trying to work out the traffic used within the billing period of the month. The billing period for the above two examples would be:

```
my_web_server:
    2014-10-30 -> 2014-11-29
    2014-09-30 -> 2014-10-29
    2014-08-30 -> 2014-09-29

my_ftp_server:
    2014-10-16 -> 2014-11-15
    2014-09-16 -> 2014-10-15
    2014-08-16 -> 2014-09-15
```

When I get the traffic for `WHERE date BETWEEN(DATE_ADD(DATE_SUB(expires, INTERVAL 1 MONTH), INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND NOW()` is within that one month period, everything is fine.

The problem occurs when the product has been renewed before expiry. This means that `expires` is greater than `INTERVAL 1 MONTH` from `NOW()`.

eg: If my_ftp_server is renewed on 2014-11-10 for instance, `expires` would then become 2014-12-10 - which would make the WHERE clause of `WHERE date BETWEEN(DATE_ADD(DATE_SUB(expires, INTERVAL 1 MONTH), INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND NOW()` return dates from 2014-11-16 to 2014-12-15 - which is actually the NEXT billing month.

As such, I need to be able to get the current billing cycle.

Thinking a bit about this out loud... if DATEDIFF(expires, NOW()) is greater than INTERVAL 1 MONTH, then traffic could be selected with `WHERE date > DATE_SUB(expires, INTERVAL 2 MONTH) - but if the difference between NOW() and`expires`is less than INTERVAL 1 MONTH, then I could use`WHERE date > DATE_SUB(expires, INTERVAL 1 MONTH)`

Comment: Not enough information. What is a billing month? Is it the same for all clients? It sounds like your system design is incomplete. You must provide a better definition of what constitutes a billing month, and if that is per client then you need another column in the `services` table defining the month boundaries distinct from the current expiration date.  Beware boundary conditions. What if the month boundary is the 31st, what happens on months with fewer days?

Comment: The period is always a month in length - and different per product.

The expires field is always the last day of the billing cycle. Therefore, DATE_SUB(expires, INTERVAL 1 MONTH) is the latest billing cycle.

MySQL seems to handle dates very well in this regards. The last day of Jan would make the last day of Feb under date manipulations - and it does proper calculations for leap years etc...

As I mentioned though - the edge case of when NOW is between DATE_SUB(expires, INTERVAL 1 MONTH) and NOW() is where things break.

Comment: @StevenHaigh . . . Your problem would be easier to understand with sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

You are using one data item, `expires` to represent two distinct pieces of information which, although they are the same most of the time, CAN differ.

You can't do that without ambiguity.

You must store them using distinct fields, one to represent the billing cycle and one to represent the paid-up expiration date. The fact that they're the same "most of the time" is immaterial.  They represent completely different data items.

If the expiration ALWAYS happens at the end of the billing cycle, and the cycle cannot ever change for a customer, you could save a few bytes by storing only the expiration month/year, but I don't think that's worth the effort, and would be much more brittle if requirements ever change.

Add a second column for the billing cycle.

Comment: I hear what you are saying, but it also seems more work to then require a separate process to work out something like: if end_cycle = expires - interval 1 month, SET end_cycle = expires to keep updating when the current billing cycle ends.